rdd.flatmap equivalent in shared cluster unity catalog
I would like to flatten this list.


            result_list.append({"ID": formatted_id_value, "TRAN_ID": TRAN_ID, "ACCT_NUM": acct_num, "TRAN_TIME": tran_time,  "TRAN_AMOUNT": tran_amount, "CARD_TRAN_AMOUNT": card_tran_amount})



This list is defined in a python function in databricks 13.3 runtime and values are appended to each key within the list iteratively.
This worked in the single cluster


result_rdd = df.rdd.flatMap(process_row)



process_row is a python function which iteratively adds values to the list.
The error thrown is

py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.rdd() is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD

I have read that databricks doesnt support this for security purposes.
Can you help with a workaround to flatten this list?

Can you add a sample input and your expected output, also is it really needed to use rdd or can we go with Dataframe.

def process_row(row):
result_list = []
formatted_id_value = row["formatted_id_value"]
TRAN_ID = row["TRAN_ID"]
acct_num = row["acct_num"]
tran_time = row["tran_time"]
tran_amount = row["tran_amount"]
card_tran_amount = row["card_tran_amount"]
result_list.append({"ID": formatted_id_value, "TRAN_ID": TRAN_ID, "ACCT_NUM": acct_num, "TRAN_TIME": tran_time,  "TRAN_AMOUNT": tran_amount, "CARD_TRAN_AMOUNT": card_tran_amount})

return result_list

result_rdd = df.rdd.flatMap(process_row)
flattened_df = result_rdd.toDF()
flattened_df.show()

can you try the above and let me know if it helped.

This is exactly what I have tried. I cant use rdd.flatmap as it is not whitelisted in databricks

I have tried the following in PySpark:
Sample data:
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| ID|TRAN_ID|ACCT_NUM|          TRAN_TIME|TRAN_AMOUNT|CARD_TRAN_AMOUNT|       result_list|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
|  1|   T001|    A001|2021-01-01 10:00:00|        100|              90|[result1, result2]|
|  2|   T002|    A002|2021-01-01 11:00:00|        200|             180|[result3, result4]|
+---+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TRAN_ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ACCT_NUM", StringType(), True),
    StructField("TRAN_TIME", StringType(), True),
    StructField("TRAN_AMOUNT", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("CARD_TRAN_AMOUNT", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("result_list", ArrayType(StringType()), True)  # Adding a new column for demonstration
])
data = [
    (1, "T001", "A001", "2021-01-01 10:00:00", 100, 90, ["result1", "result2"]),
    (2, "T002", "A002", "2021-01-01 11:00:00", 200, 180, ["result3", "result4"]),
    
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()
flattened_df = df.selectExpr("ID", "explode(result_list) AS result")
flattened_df.show()

Results:
+---+-------+
| ID| result|
+---+-------+
|  1|result1|
|  1|result2|
|  2|result3|
|  2|result4|
+---+-------+

I have defined the schema for the DataFrame. In the above code, I am flattening the column result_list using explode and selecting the columns ID and the exploded column.
